# How to index/slice 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I'm relatively new to python/numpy.  I have a 3D numpy array of TxNxN.  It contains a sequence of symmetrical NxN matrices.  I want convert it to a 2D array of TxM (where M = N(N+1)/2).  How can I do that?  I can certainly use 3 loops, but I thought there probably better ways to do that in python/numpy.

Comment: You need to understand slicing in numpy first, thats the direction to look at, and it can be done on 1 loop, by iterating only on the 3rd dimension. on each iteration you will need to instantiate and create a 2D array that you can store either on a list, a variable, a file (probably as an image, I have no context on your problem).

Comment: Show us the 3 loops first!  And as a bonus - your attempt(s) at "better" ways.

Comment: Basically:
1. do a `for` loop across the `X` dimension (in this case I'll take the 3rd for example), in this case: `for k in range(N)`
2. do something for each iteration of k. Example: `slice = my3dnumpyarray[:, :, k]`

Note: each `:` means that you are taking the whole range (domain) of that dimension, if the first dimension goes from `0` to `T - 1` then the first `:` means exactly that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to get the upper triangle or lower triangle of each symmetric matrix. A simple method is to generate a mask array and apply it to each 2D array:

```
>>> e
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3, 0],
        [2, 3, 0, 1],
        [3, 0, 1, 2]],

       [[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4, 1],
        [3, 4, 1, 2],
        [4, 1, 2, 3]],

       [[2, 3, 4, 5],
        [3, 4, 5, 2],
        [4, 5, 2, 3],
        [5, 2, 3, 4]]])
>>> ii, jj = np.indices(e.shape[1:])
>>> jj >= ii
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True]])
>>> e[:, jj >= ii]
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Using the `numpy.triu_indices` function can do better, but you can't put the obtained indices tuple directly between square brackets. You need to unpack them first:

```
>>> i, j = np.triu_indices(e.shape[1])
>>> e[:, i, j]
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4]])
```